# Elasticsearch Lucene query syntax to add and subtract N minutes with time field?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I am working on grafana dashboard in that, I passing start time and end time from one dashboard to another using template variable. This is how I passing the value

```
var-startTime=2020-07-23T05:07:04Z&var-endTime=2020-07-23T05:11:31Z
```

In another dashboard, I get the variable values and pass to Lucene query like

```
@timestamp:[$startTime TO $endTime]
```

It's working fine. But here I want to get data prior to 15 minutes from start time and 15 minutes later from end time. How could I add and subtract 15 minutes with this time? I need something like this.

```
@timestamp:[$startTime-15m TO $endTime+15m]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Lucene expression language you can do exactly that using the [`||` anchor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math):

```
@timestamp:[2020-07-23T05:07:04Z||-15m TO 2020-07-23T05:11:31Z||+15m]
```

So I guess you can have something like

```
@timestamp:[$startTime||-15m TO $endTime||+15m]
```

Comment: bounty has 5 more days to expire. can I use this for another question?